# introduction to latex

Tags: latex

what's a good website that has an introduction to latex for window users? I will be using it mainly to write math homework problems and probably then converting it to a PDF to print out. I'm hoping somebody has bookmarked a good link already so I don't have to search. Thanks!

Comment: A better place for LaTeX questions is http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that Andy Roberts's site is perfect for beginners, it has a lot of newbie exercises and takes you by the hand in a perfectly controlled fashion. It is my online reference for my basic latex questions.

http://www.andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You should start from this "not so short introduction to latex"
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this one: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

LaTeX works the same across platforms (and even across its distros, except some may provide features that others don't), so it doesn't really matter what your platform is.

Answer (score 1):

The [LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/) site doesn't seem to have any beginner tutorials, but it does have a number of articles that go into specific uses. If one of those articles covers what you're trying to do, then it may give you a headstart.

Outside tutorials, as a beginner getting into LaTeX, I found the [TeXnicCenter Open Source IDE](http://www.texniccenter.org/) to be very useful. It makes life a lot easier when you get some syntax colouring and templates to help with common structures like tables.

Comment: It should be mentioned that TeXnicCenter’s lack of Unicode support makes baby Jesus cry. I suggest using a modern editor like Notepad++ instead.